# Possible evaluation or validation of predicted 3D protein structure generated by SCWRL4

Tags: protein-structure

I mutated a wild type protein structure using Scwrl4. How can I evaluate or validate the reliability of the predicted structure generated by Scwrl4?

Comment: The quick answer is to use thermodynamic stability programs such as mCSM and SDM type approaches. Is this what you had in mind?